# how to use input variable for file name in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to do this `with open(fileName,'rb') as csvfile:`. It works if I hardcode a name for fileName, but if I use `fileName = input("Enter file name: ")` I get an error

```
...
fileName = input("Enter file name: ")
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'page1' is not defined
```

where `page1.csv` is the intended file and what I enter for when asked for input. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using Python 2. You need to use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

`raw_input` will give you a string value as you expect. `input` tries to run it as a Python expression.

Comment: wow thanks for that. I'm not working from my usual computer and totally forgot to check the version. Stupid mistake